# Xcode 8 beta 4: Calendar.Unit vs Calendar.Component

Tags: swift3, xcode8, xcode8-beta4

This Swift 3 code worked until XCode 8 beta 3:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let anchorComponents = calendar.components([Calendar.Unit.day, Calendar.Unit.month, Calendar.Unit.year, Calendar.Unit.hour], from: self)
```

In Xcode 8 beta 4 `Calendar.Unit` appears to be renamed to `Calendar.Component`.

Now this code

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let anchorComponents = calendar.components([Calendar.Component.day, Calendar.Component.month, Calendar.Component.year, Calendar.Component.hour], from: self)
```

produces the compiler error `cannot convert value of type Calendar.Component to NSCalendar.Unit`

Am I doing anything wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In the Swift version shipped with Xcode 8 beta 4, `components` has been renamed to `dateComponents`.

Note: to make the call simpler, you can omit the `Calendar.Component` prefix.

```
let anchorComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year, .hour], from: self)
```

The error message you got is a bit misleading, I guess the compiler was struggling with type inference.

Comment: If you're not using this in a Date extension you have to replace `self` by a proper date object.

Answer (score 31):

### **Swift 3 and Swift 4:**

In this example you could also prepare your unitFlags from/to date:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.current
let unitFlags = Set<Calendar.Component>([.day, .month, .year, .hour])
let anchorComponents = calendar.dateComponents(unitFlags, from: startDate as Date,  to: endDate as Date)
```