# NSCalendar in Swift3

Tags: swift3, xcode8

before Swift3, in a my project I used this function:

```
var components = (calendar as NSCalendar).components([.year, .monthSymbols, .firstWeekday, .timeZone, .hour, .minute], from: data_corrente)
```

Now I'm changing the project using swift 3 (xCode8 beta5) but I have this error:

> Type 'NSCalendar.Unit has no member 'monthSymbol'

Can someone explain where is the problem and help me to solve it? I think is a migration problem

Comment: Instead of downcasting to NSCalendar, just use Calendar, with "dateComponents" and short syntax for components: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38720438/2227743

Comment: Are you using the same project as the guy in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38920909/xcode-8-and-swift-3-nscalendar ? `timeZone`, `monthSymbol` and `firstWeekday` have never been calendar units / components.

Comment: I removed forstWeekDay and monthSymbol... even if in the previous version all were compiled with success

Comment: Swift 3 is still beta ...

Comment: When I use Xcode 7 ... the compiler don't show me error..

Comment: Which calendar class in Swift 2 requires to be bridged to `NSCalendar`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Swift3 with Xcode8 beta.
You can use `Calendar` instead of `NSCalendar` as like this:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let component = calendar.dateComponents([.day,.month,.year], from: Date())
```

Comment: Do you have any examples using this component?